# Can I take a photo of/from the video feed in Teamviewer?

Tags: teamviewer

I would like to take a snapshot/photo from the video feed in a Teamviewer 11 session.

(I have tried doing a screeshot of MY screen showing THEIR video but that's not high enough resolution)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is included under "Extras" in TeamViewer 9 and higher (can confirm the feature exists in version 11). See [page 16](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/res/pdf/TeamViewer9-Manual-RemoteControl-EN.pdf) of the TeamViewer9 Manual.

> **Take screenshot**... Saves the currently displayed contents of the
>   remote control window as a screenshot. To do so, click Take
>   screenshot…. In the opened dialog box, you will have the option to
>   save the screenshot or copy it to the clipboard.

If you are unable to use this version, you can send the remote client a Print Screen keystroke, save the file, then transfer it locally.